# XQuery: Merge Nodes of Same Name

Tags: xquery

How would I take all element nodes of the same name, and combine them together into one that retains the child elements of each?

Example input:

```
<topic>
  <title />
  <language />
  <more-info>
    <itunes />
  </more-info>
  <more-info>
    <imdb />
  </more-info>
  <more-info>
    <netflix />
  </more-info>
</topic>
```

Example output (all of the `more-info`s are collapsed into a single element):

```
<topic>
  <title />
  <language />
  <more-info>
    <itunes />
    <imdb />
    <netflix />
  </more-info>
</topic>
```

**Edit:** I am looking for a way to do this without knowing which node names reoccur. So, with the example above, I could not use a script that only targeted `more-info`, as there may be other elements that also need to have the same process applied to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with that:

```xquery
for $n in $nodes/node()
let $lname := local-name($n)
group by $lname
return element {$lname} {
  $n/node()
}
```

Where `$nodes` contains the input document.

It uses a `group by` which will bind the `$n` variable to the list of grouped nodes.
So, the expression `$n/node()` represent a sequence of node.

To make it recursive, we have to declare a function and call it:

```xquery
declare function local:recurse($node){
  for $n in $node/text() return $n,
  for $n in $node/element()
  let $lname := local-name($n)
  group by $lname
  return element {$lname} {
    for $m in $n return local:recurse($m)
  }
};

local:recurse($nodes)
```

The first line ends with a comma. It's a list concatenation. So, we output text nodes first, then element nodes with the `group by` sheningan explained above.

### XML Input

```xml
<topic>
  <title>Test</title>
  <language />
  <more-info>
    <itunes>
      <playlist>
        <item>2</item>
      </playlist>
      <playlist>
        <item>3</item>
      </playlist>
    </itunes>
  </more-info>
  <more-info>
    <imdb>Imdb info</imdb>
  </more-info>
  <more-info>
    <netflix>Netflix info</netflix>
  </more-info>
</topic>
```

### XML Output

```xml
<title>Test</title>
<language/>
<more-info>
  <itunes>
    <playlist>
      <item>2</item>
      <item>3</item>
    </playlist>
  </itunes>
  <imdb>Imdb info</imdb>
  <netflix>Netflix info</netflix>
</more-info>
```

### Remarks

I have no clues why XSLT is deemed easier. Maybe the `apply-templates` is masquerading the recursion, making it less intimidating.

Also, the fact that the matching is declared outside the "loop" make it easier (then, has to be paired with mode for full control) compared to XQuery which required it inside the "loop".

Whatever, in this peculiar example, `XQuery` seems to be very appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
declare option saxon:output "omit-xml-declaration=yes";
<topic>
  <title />
  <language />
  <more-info>
   {for $inf in /*/more-info/node()
     return $inf
   }
  </more-info>
</topic>
```

**When this XQuery is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<topic>
  <title />
  <language />
  <more-info>
    <itunes />
  </more-info>
  <more-info>
    <imdb />
  </more-info>
  <more-info>
    <netflix />
  </more-info>
</topic>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<topic>
   <title/>
   <language/>
   <more-info>
      <itunes/>
      <imdb/>
      <netflix/>
   </more-info>
</topic>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but what I was looking for was a way to merge them when I don’t know which nodes reoccur. I should have been more specific; I’ve updated the OP.

Comment: @HughGuiney, In such case you are really much better off with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a better job for XSLT if you can use it.

**XML Input**

```
<topic>
    <title />
    <language />
    <more-info>
        <itunes />
    </more-info>
    <more-info>
        <imdb />
    </more-info>
    <more-info>
        <netflix />
    </more-info>
</topic>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<topic>
   <title/>
   <language/>
   <more-info>
      <itunes/>
      <imdb/>
      <netflix/>
   </more-info>
</topic>
```

Comment: I can use it, but will you please explain why XSLT is a better choice here?